# WidgetAnalogClock not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer (or drawing cache) needs 2250000 bytes only 1639680 available

Tags: widget, android-6.0-marshmallow

WidgetAnalogClock not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer (or drawing cache)  needs 2250000 bytes only 1639680 available